# Include pega caminho errado da url

Tags: php, html, include

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que o arquivo, dentro de `views/usuarios/usuarios-view.php`, incluísse o arquivo `_layout.html` que está no caminho:  `views/_template/_layout.html`, estou fazendo assim no `usuarios-view.php`:

```
<?php include ("../_template/_layout.html"); ?>
```

Entretanto ele pega o caminho:

http://localhost/medic/views/usuarios/_template/dist/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css

Quando deveria pegar o caminho:

http://localhost/medic/views/_template/dist/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Usa o caminho absoluto, ou http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: @user5978 o ruim é que se usar assim, quando jogar para o servidor terei que mudar o caminho de lá também.

Comment: Não vejo outro solução para isso, por o que gera o "problema" é o comportamento do browser, e não do seu sistema, então está "fora do seu alcace".

Comment: `<?php include ("../../_template/_layout.html"); ?>`

Comment: A melhor forma é como o @mauhumor falou usando a tag base.
Mas você pode popular ela usando a variavel global do php $_SERVER, usando os valores SERVER_NAME e REQUEST_URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução encontrada foi passar o caminho absoluto para o include da seguinte forma:

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/medic/views/_template/_layout.html';
```

Para links, o ideal seria usar o `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`:

```
<a href="http://<?=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?>/medic/index.php"></a>
```